# Adding external script in meteor and controlling their load order using es6 imports

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, ecmascript-6

I am learning meteor and working on my first project. I am impressed by its great power but recently i have stumbled upon a problem which could not be solved after hours spent on Google and Stack Overflow.

I have structured my project as advised in the meteor documentation  [here](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#javascript-structure) .

Following is the structure of my project

[image]

To control the load order, I wrote the following code in imports/startup/client/loader_conf.js

```
// importing files in the desired order

// loading jquery before materialize
import '../lib/jquery-3.1.0.min.js';

import '../lib/materialize.min.css';
import '../lib/materialize.min.js';
```

and following code in imports/startup/client/loader_conf.js

```
import './loader_conf.js';
```

Then finally to load the complete load configuration as a module in my client side added following line to the top of the eagerly loaded 
client/main.js

```
import '/imports/startup/client';
```

As evident, I drew analogy the the example project structure provided in the doc.

But after doing all this, which looked quite promising, I am getting following errors in the terminal

```
Unable to resolve some modules:

  "jquery" in                                 
/home/siteflu/VAIBHAV/meteor/demo/imports/startup/lib/materialize.min.js(web.browser)

  "hammerjs" in                               
/home/siteflu/VAIBHAV/meteor/demo/imports/startup/lib/materialize.min.js(web.browser)
  "./picker.js" in                            
/home/siteflu/VAIBHAV/meteor/demo/imports/startup/lib/materialize.min.js(web.browser)

If you notice problems related to these missing modules, consider running:

  meteor npm install --save jquery hammerjs
```

and in the browser I get the error

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'
```

I have checked that $() and jQuery() are working in the console.

I am really confused in this whole file loading and imports thing.

After googling a lot, I got to know that there are other ways of achieving the same thing for example:

1. Using packages
2. Keeping the files in public folder and including script tag in the head
3. Using jquery to load script using Template.onRendered().

But I feel these imports way is better and more standardized way.

Please help me with find the problem in this way.

Comment: Did you install *jquery* and *hammerjs* in the npm dependency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer. Actually i did not understand the internals of meteor working that were posing the issue in integrating third party libraries.

Actually Meteor wraps all the javascript written into a new variable scope internally.

Got to know the above detail from this informative response by hwilson on the meteor [thread](https://forums.meteor.com/t/adding-external-script-in-meteor-and-controlling-their-load-order-using-es6-imports/27824) i created.

You can visit the thread for details.

Cheers..